# php read variables from sql result

Tags: php, string, mysqli

I'm working with some dynamic strings in php.
This should create a string like:

> Hey Deben Oldert

Where Deben and Oldert are both variables.

```
$firstname = "Deben";
$lastname = "Oldert";

$body = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT body FROM mail WHERE type='{$_GET['type']}'"))['body'].PHP_EOL;

//The body field contains <p>Hey $firstname $lastname</p>

echo $body
```

It outputs `Hey $firstname $lastname`
When I tried

```
$a = 'Deben';
$b = 'Oldert';
$b = "Hey $a $b".PHP_EOL;
echo $b;
```

It outputs `Hey Deben Oldert`

So why isn't it working from a mysqli_fetch result?

Comment: The string containing variables stored in the DB table will not automatically interpolate the variables from the current scope. That string is _just a string_, it is not PHP code.

Comment: A side note - it's not a good idea to nest `mysqli_query()` inside a fetch call. If it fails (which it easily could given direct unfiltered input from `$_GET`), the entire program breaks.

Comment: You might consider storing the string in a format for `sprintf()` like `<p>Hey %s %s</p>` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will parse a double quoted string and substitute in variable values. But it won't parse the contents of a variable and do that.

So when you print `"Hey $a $b"`, it will replace `$a` and `$b` with their values.
But when you do echo $b, it print what's in $b - it won't parse it first.
Similarly if you did `'Hey $a $b'`, it will not parse that.

You would usually do your own substitution when you're getting a pattern from the database, eg. with [printf()](http://php.net/printf).